# How I can take the text from a modal pop up

Tags: selenium

```
<h6 class="modal-title" style="position:center;">Training Slots Booked Successfully</h6>
```

I need to retrieve "Training Slots booked successfully" from the above and have to store it in a string. How can I do it?? I tried as below but it was not working

```
String message = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"AddTrainingSlotsResultModal\"]/div/div/div[1]/h6")).getText();
```

Comment: <h6 class="modal-title" style="position:center;">Training Slots Booked Successfully</h6>

Comment: @KunduK Not working :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Induce `WebDriverWait` and `elementToBeClickable`() and following xpath.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//h6[@class='modal-title']")));
String message =element.getText()
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. what makes the difference here?? can u explain be briefly?

Comment: The modal box takes some time to load when induce WebDriverWait it will wait until element is clickable.make a note this is the best practice when you  interact with web app.